# Proper way to structure API Services / TypeScript-Next.js-Server Actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a bunch of server actions `( createProduct ,getProductAssets .. )` and each of these actions check the user session if its valid first upon request.

I want to check session only once if its valid then call the wanted function...

So how should I structure my product-actions/index file ?

One of the functions:

```js
export async function getProductAssets(productId: string) {
          try {
            const session: Session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
            if (!session.user) {
              return {
                success: false,
                message: 'Unauthorized!',
              };
            }
```

Comment: If you were using api routes you could use middleware, with server actions I dont think its possible, not easily anyway. One way would be to abstract the auth code into a function and make it short and sweet, checkSession(session). But really, there shouldnt be a function call in the first place if they are not authed.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check session only once if its valid then call the wanted
> function...

this does not make sense. because, server actions are aync functions that run exclusively on the server, invoked by user interactions on the client side. If a server sction performs sensitive actions like accessing private resources, verifying the user's session ensures that only authorized users can execute those actions.

let's say you checked the session first and you got a valid session. But after 2 minutes user invoked another action, maybe `createProduct` action, if the session expired at that time and you do not check session, anyone could potentially forge requests to create products, even if not logged in or authorized. this could lead to unauthorized product listings